# Click event id not firing using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please tell me why the click event is not firing? I add click event like this:

```
$('.addClickClass').click(function(){
    alert('hi') ;                      
})
```

There is button "add test case". It generates a row. Now, when I expand it click expanded button. It does not fire.

Secondly how can I tell which row button is fired? If I press "add test case" 3 times, how I could I know which one I pressed?

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R2DzV/11/)**

Comment: Its working here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R2DzV/12/). Changed option from left side of fiddle option `No wrap - in <body>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attaching the event listener *before* adding the element to the DOM.  Move it inside     `$('.btn_handler').click(function () {`

The code is run on page load.  At that point, there are no elements with the class `addClickClass`, so no event handler is added.  Moving it to after the call to `append` means that you've added elements with the class `addClickClass`, so jQuery is able to attach the event listener at that time.

http://jsfiddle.net/R2DzV/13/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/R2DzV/14/ is the answer ...Got it how to know which option is selected

Comment: @user944513 btw best practice would be to bind on.click event to closest static element on the page, binding it to window feels kind of stretch.

Comment: ``$('#list').on('click','.addClickClass',function(){});``

Comment: thanks ..sir great answer..can you look on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738481/how-to-know-which-radio-button-id-selected-of-which-row

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to bind an event to an element that does not exist on the page yet.

You have bind it after your create it, or you can use [jQuery's `on` method](https://api.jquery.com/on/) and delegate an event to the document. Then all your new elements will have this event.

Comment: Second Question anwser ?

Comment: how to know which add button is call first row or second ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/R2DzV/14/ is the answer ...Got it how to know which option is selected

Answer (score 0):

because your "addClickClass" element is added dynamically you should replace your code with this :

```
 $("#list").on('click', '.addClickClass',function(){
      alert('hi') ;                      
  })
```