# how to know which radio button id selected of which row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have make a demo in which I make rows with ids `tc_1`, `tc_2`, `tc_3` …… and so on.

When I expand a row, I have two options and a button. I need to get know which row id and which option is selected?

Example: I expand second row, It should alert `tc_1` with option select **Add test case**.

```
$('#list').on('click','.addClickClass',function(){
    alert('hii')
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the row id and the value of checked radio, use this:

```
$('#list').on('click','.addClickClass',function(){
     alert($(this).parents('li[id*="tc"]').attr('id') + "\n" 
         + $(this).parents('.ui-collapsible').find('input:checked').val())
 })
```

It gives you output like this, for example:

```
tc_1
TestCommand
```

which I believe is exactly what you're looking for.

I used this to fetch the row id:

```
$(this).parents('li[id*="tc"]').attr('id')
```

and this to get the checked radio value:

```
$(this).parents('.ui-collapsible').find('input:checked').val()
```

Both related to the clicked Add button.

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/R2DzV/16/

Answer (score 1):

Here's some new jquery code for your `alert` that gets the id of the selected element:

```
 alert('hi from ' + $(e.target).closest('[datarole="collapsible"]').find('input:checked').attr('id') )
```

Here's a forked jsfiddle showing this working change: http://jsfiddle.net/mstapp/mGSJ7/1/

Answer (score 0):

In cases like those jQuery will provide you with element object in question `$(this)`:

```
$('#list').on('click','.addClickClass',function(){
    // This is current button clicked
    console.log($(this));
});
```

If you want to get to some specific item from button you have whole documentation to choose from.  But for example sake lets say you want to find `li` that wraps all case:

```
$('#list').on('click','.addClickClass',function(){
    //  Get the first ancestor that matches a selector
    $(this).closest('li');
});
```

There's tons of great material on traversing and manipulating [Traversing - Manipulating](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/traversing-manipulating)

Comment: But it does not give which option i selected ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```js
$('#list').on('click','.addClickClass',function(){
    alert($(this).closest('div').parent().parent().prop('id'));
});
```

Comment: how ot know which option is selectes

Comment: Forget my answer, Shomz's answer is far better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try this:

```
$('#list').on('click', '.addClickClass', function () {
    var row = $(this).parents('li').eq(1); // top second parent
    var selected = row.find('label[data-icon="radio-on"] .ui-btn-text').text();
    alert(row.attr('id') + "\n" + selected);
});
```

But you need to be careful, if there will be more `<li>` elements you need to specify which one to target.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/R2DzV/17/)

Answer (score 0):

After:

```
    $('#list').trigger('create');
```

Add handler for radio change event:

```
    var $appendedLi = $("#list>li:last-child");
    $appendedLi.find ("input[type='radio']").on ("change", function () {
         if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
             alert("Current row: " + $(this).closest("#list>li").attr("id"));
             alert("Selected option: " + $(this).val());
         }
    });
```